# Restrict user-defined T-SQL query to SELECT type only

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am working on an app that is providing a way for an user to define a SQL query and run it against the database. The only purpose of the query is to create a dataset which will be used to build a report. As this is a shared database (meaning large number of accounts with per-account tables), security is very important.

I am looking for the best way to verify that the supplied query is SELECT type only - meaning the user cannot run DELETE, UPDATE, etc.. Of course, the verification must be server side. The project is written in C#.

The first check is to verify that the query begins with SELECT, but it is not enough because of sub-queries. I was thinking to verify if the query string (C#) contains some reserved words like: EXEC, DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT.

Are there any ways to "hack" this verification (using &nbsp or other chars) ? Which reserved words must be blocked ? Any other thoughts or ideas ?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: If security is very important, do not do this. Think about a different approach !

Comment: Do you want to allow the use of user defined functions? Can you achieve your desired level of security by restricting access, i.e. only granting read access to the data the user should be able to see?

Comment: @Kaf there is no different approach to implement the requirement (at least I don't see any)

Comment: @HABO no user defined functions, just SELECT for creating datasets - user has full data access as he can execute large number of already predefined queries

Comment: Can you force the query to execute in a different security context? See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188315(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The following code grants permissions on SELECT, and deny permissions on SQL keywords that may cause malicious attacks:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SchemaName TO UserName
DENY ALTER ON SchemaName TO UserName
DENY CREATE ON SchemaName TO UserName
DENY INSERT ON SchemaName TO UserName
DENY UPDATE ON SchemaName TO UserName
DENY DELETE ON SchemaName TO UserName
DENY DROP ON SchemaName TO UserName
DENY TRUNCATE ON SchemaName TO UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the user a restricted GUI where they can point-and-click? That way the query is correct by construction.

Next idea would be to create a special user which has only the right permissions. This should be 100% reliable according to the docs (if it was not, it would be impossible to secure the server). But I don't trust that 100% because there can be bugs in SQL Server or your implementation of security. Decide yourself whether this is enough for you.

Alternatively, use SMO to parse the query and validate it. Make sure that it conforms to a white-listed format (e.g. exactly one `SELECT`, no function invocations, no `EXEC`, ...). This is hard.

Comment: We used point-and-click before, but it is too limited - the user must be able to build complex queries. I don't think creating special user type is an option, because the same user is also able to run a large number of other queries (software defined).

White-listing the query seems the way to go, but as you said it is hard to think about all scenarios. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you use the restricted user for just that reporting query? Just change the connection string for that query. IMO this is the only practical way for you to allow free-form queries. You can even use Resource Governor to limit resource usage and make the queries safe. Have the query run under SNAPSHOT isolation to make it concurrency-safe (no blocking, no deadlocking). Set a low CommandTimeout.